# JQuery UI Dialog html() and fadein crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using dialog jquery UI, and i apply html() and fadein() when the user submit the correct inputs. When the DOM read this line, it's crashed (i try debugger and it's crashed in this line), and i don't know why because before it's works like a charm. Console doesn't throws me any error or warning (i'm using chrome last version):

```
("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close')
      }, 2000)
```

HTML structure of the dialog:

```
      <div id="message" class="row-fluid hidden"></div>

    <div id="page" class="row-fluid"><div class="page-header"><div id="dialog" style="display: none;" title="Task detail">

    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myform" novalidate="">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email address</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="" aria-invalid="true">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group error">
                            <label class="control-label" for="emailAgain">Email again</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="email" data-validation-matches-match="email" data-validation-matches-message="Must match email address entered above" class="form-control" id="emailAgain" name="emailAgain" aria-invalid="false">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="terms-and-conditions">Legal</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="terms-and-conditions" name="terms-and-conditions" required="" data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions" aria-invalid="true">
                                    I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Quality Control</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="fast" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="2" data-validation-minchecked-message="Choose two" data-validation-maxchecked-maxchecked="2" data-validation-maxchecked-message="You can't have it all ways" aria-invalid="true">
                                    Fast
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="cheap" aria-invalid="false">
                                    Cheap
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="good" aria-invalid="false">
                                    Good
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="btnSave" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success modalbtn">Guardar cambios</button>
    <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default modalbtn cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
</div>
                    </form>

    </div>
    </div>  </div>
```

JQuery structure:

```
$('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation(
  {

    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) { 
        $('#btnSave')[0].disabled = false;
      $("#myform").effect( "shake" );
    }
  }
);
$('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation(
  {
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event, errors) { 
        $('#btnSave')[0].disabled = false;

      $("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close')
      }, 2000)

    }
  }
);
```

Validation works, it's shake when it's not correct but when i click in save changes and all it's correct (submitSuccess Function), it's crashed and close the dialog...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure from your html code about whether you want to show the dialogue or fade out it upon success. But I created a fiddle from you code which works fine. Upon successful validation it fades in the muchas gracias! message. I updated the js code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation(
  {

    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) { 
        $('#btnSave')[0].disabled = false;
      $("#myform").effect( "shake" );
    },
      submitSuccess: function ($form, event,errors) {
        $('#btnSave')[0].disabled = false; 
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close')
      }, 2000)

    }
  }
);   

});
```

Check the fiddle, use the code from it and let me know if it stops crashing.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKN4b/

Comment: Now i stop crashing, if it going to crash again i'm going to tell you quickly. Thanks a lot!! EDIT: I don't know why when i click in the botton for open the modal, i scroll to the bottom of the page and the modal is in the top... Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848416/click-on-jquery-ui-dialog-button-go-to-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is but you can try this out

```
$("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow', function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#dialog').dialog('close')
   }, 2000)
});
```