# If not have class change color text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and i want to change the label color only when the control-group doesn't have the class error, because when the user submit invalid text in the input the control group div add class .error to show red div and red text.

I tried this inserting ! for (if not) but this overwrite the class .error to add the color #222, i don't want this...

```
$(".form-control").focus(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().parent().parent().is('.error')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({
            color: '#222 !important;'
        });
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().parent().parent().is('.error')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({
            color: '#ccc !important;'
        });
    }
})
```

HTML Code of the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myform" novalidate="">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Nombre</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="name" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Debes escribir tu nombre" name="name" id="name" required="true" aria-invalid="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="No has escrito correctamente el correo electrónico" name="email" id="email" required="" aria-invalid="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emailAgain">Correo electrónico (otra vez)</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" data-validation-matches-match="email" data-validation-matches-message="Los correos electrónicos no coinciden" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Debes escribir el mismo correo electrónico" required="true" id="emailAgain" name="emailAgain" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="terms-and-conditions">Advertencia legal</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms-and-conditions" name="terms-and-conditions" required="" data-validation-required-message="Debes estar de acuerdo con los términos y condiciones" aria-invalid="true">
                Estoy de acuerdo con los <a id="legal" data-content="CoolFitness se reserva el derecho a usar dicho correo para realizar análisis estadísticos que sin duda te beneficiarán." rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Términos y condiciones" data-trigger="hover" href="#">términos y condiciones</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Información sobre</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="dietas" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" data-validation-minchecked-message="Elige una al menos" aria-invalid="true">
                Dietas
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="ej-fitness" aria-invalid="false">
                Ejercicios Fitness
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="qualityControl[]" value="encuestas" aria-invalid="false">
                Encuestas
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnSave" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success modalbtn">Guardar cambios</button>
        <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default modalbtn cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
    <audio>
        <source src="sounds/correct.mp3"></source>
    </audio>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code to your question. It's a little hard to visualise what you mean.

Comment: you can use [jQuery's :not selector](http://api.jquery.com/:not/) e.g: `.not('.error')`

Comment: But .not is applying my color: #ccc to my .control-group error too. I put this: $(".form-control").focus(function(){
 if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().not('.error')) {
   $(this).parent().parent().css({color: '#222;'});
   }   

}).blur(function(){
 if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().not('.error')) {
   $(this).parent().parent().css({color: '#ccc !important;'});
   }   

  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just with CSS.

```
label {color:blue;}
.error label {color:red;}

.form-control {color:#ccc;}
.form-control:focus {color:#222;}
.error .form-control:focus {color:red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45nLw/

UPDATE: It wasn't entirely clear from your question just what you're requirements were. Following your comment I *think* you want to change the `label` colour when a (not errored) field is in focus. If that is the case then try the following JS:

```
$(".form-control").focus(function(){
    $(this).parents(".control-group:not(.error)").find("label").css("color","#222");
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).parents(".control-group:not(.error)").find("label").css("color","#ccc");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45nLw/2/

UPDATE: Still struggling to understand your requirements.
This? http://jsfiddle.net/ksapq/7/

Comment: But i want to do with the label text color on focus not with the input text color

Comment: It works ok but overwrite the control group .error and delete the class .error when it applies the color text change...

Comment: I don't understand. It doesn't overwrite any classes. Do you want it to?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what you are trying to achieve. What should happen to the `.error` boxes when you focus on a field?

Comment: Okay i found that delete's error class in focus by the plugin, check the html in the control-group in the official example of the page: reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/ how can solve this and not delete class error?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is is `.hasClass()` to check if the element has the sepcific class you want.

http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

So your checking code can be something like below:

```
if (!$(this).parent().parent().parent().hasClass('error')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({
            color: '#222'
        });
    }
```

Check below fiddle and you will see your code works with hasClass(). The color of text will change to gray on focus and black on blur.

**Important:** Remove the `!important` tag from the css that you apply with jquery.css(). It won't apply the css to the element with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/x79J6/

Comment: I tried with it but hasclass overwrite my .error classes when the validation fails if i focus an input.

Comment: no hasCLass will not overwrite any class. hasClass only checks for the class. .addClass() can add other class. Also, did you use the dot before the class name while using hasClass()?

Comment: It's overwrite the .error class to me, can you apply it here?: http://jsfiddle.net/ksapq/3/

Comment: Yea, updated it. http://jsfiddle.net/ksapq/5/  You needed to remove the !important mark fromt he css that you apply.

Comment: I do discover that the dialog dissapear because a problem in the plugin, it crashes. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: @PCM ok, which dialog?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828560/jquery-ui-dialog-html-and-fadein-crash